# Add multiple values and names to a CSS style property

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

I'm currently loading a font with Font.js. The font has multiple AXIS values that I want to animate. It's rather simple because of the CSS property font-variation-settings.

Problem: I can't set the CSS property. The font-variation-settings needs to be displayed like

```
.class{
 font-variation-settings: "wght" 200, "slnt" 150, "mono" 0;
}
```

How can I add those attributes to the CSS?
I can't use commands like `container.style.setProperty(slider.id, slider.value)`, because that would just add one AXIS to the property.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the values in an object and map them into the style property like this:

```
var axes = {
    'wght': 200,
    'slnt': 150,
    'mono': 0,
}

function makeFontVariationSettings(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj)
        .map(function(key) { 
            return `"${key}" ${obj[key]}`; 
        })
        .join(', ');
}

var fontVariationSettings = makeFontVariationSettings(axes);
container.style.setProperty('font-variation-settings', fontVariationSettings);
```

Comment: While the global idea is good, I'm not sure a `reduce` is really useful here. I'll one-line it for brevity: `return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) { return \`"${key}" ${obj[key]}\`; }).join(', ');` (assuming we're in the `makeFontVariationSettings` function).

Comment: @chriskirknielsen agreed! My coffee hasn't kicked in yet today ;) I will update the answer, thanks.